# unable to use square() function c++

Tags: c++, function, cmath

I'm new to C++ and I'm using the book ["Programming Principles and Practice Using C++"](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming) by Bjarne Stroustrup (I will use this book in a future school course). The code samples in this book make use of [std_lib_facilities.h](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h). At some point the book calls the function `square()`, but when I do that I get the following error:

```
error C3861: 'square': identifier not found
```

On the other hand, I am able to use the `sqrt()` function... I do include the `std_lib_facilities.h`, and that one includes the `cmath`, so I think thats is not the problem?

What should I do to use the `square()` function?

Comment: You can't use it because it doesn't exist. Either multiply the value by itself or use pow (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) with 2 as the exponent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `square` function declared or defined in that header (proof: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>).

There isn't one in the standard library, either.

From what I can tell from the book, it mentions this function as an example of a function that you can define *yourself*, and shows you how to do that. It's not expected to be readily-available.

Comment: Yes, I see now indeed that it is an example of a function to write ourselves. Just an other case of "reading too fast". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about define it yourself or simply use a multiply operator?

And for your information, C++ does not define a square function in the standard definition.

Answer (score 0):

Stuck on same example from same book. I removed square and used `*` . Works fine.  Example;

```
cout<< i<<'  \ t'<< i* i<<" \n";
```